# Problem with response status code saying response is not defined

Tags: python, zendesk, zendesk-api

Basically, I am trying to pass a list of ids in payloads of 100 from a spreadsheet to delete organizations using the destroy many endpoint.

```
import json
import xlrd
import requests


session = requests.Session()
session.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
session.auth = 'my email', 'password'
url = 'https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/destroy_many.json'

payloads = []
organizations_dict = {}
book = xlrd.open_workbook('orgs_list_destroy.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    if sheet.row_values(row)[2]:
        organizations_dict = {'ids': int(sheet.row_values(row)[2])}

        if len(organizations_dict) == 100:
            payloads.append(json.dumps(organizations_dict))
        organizations_dict = {}

        if organizations_dict:
            payloads.append(json.dumps(organizations_dict))

        for payload in payloads:
            response = session.delete(url, data=payload)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print('Import failed with status {}'.format(response.status_code))
        exit()
        print('Successfully imported a batch of organizations')
```

Comment: Hi Dustin 
 your endpoint url seems to be correct, but i m unsure of the approach. 

You need to read the ids from the xls. and append upto 100 ids in the url and hit that url. If the no of organizations is > 100 , you need to batch the operation for 100 ids each.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing it outside the for loop, where you're defining your request headers:

```
url = 'https://{{YOURDOMAIN}}.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations/destroy_many.json'
user = 'YOUR_EMAIL@DOMAIN.com' + '/token'
pwd = '{{YOUR_TOKEN}}'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.delete(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)
```